# I want to move magento2 to live server but No app/etc/local.xml in my magento 2?

Tags: local.xml, xampp

I am trying to move my local Magento site to my Live server. (XAMPP to cPanel)

To do this I have exported the database, etc and all those steps are fine.

However i get error on tables in my phpmyadmin on cpanel, also i read that i should edit the `local.xml` file but i don't have that file in my app/etc folder rather i have `config.php`, `env.php`, di(which is xml)file.

Does anybody know if I am doing this step correctly, or is there a different way to get my Magento files from my Local site to my Live site. or how i can manually set `local.xml` in magento 2.0

My env.php looks like this

```
<?php
  return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
  'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
 'install' => 
  array (

 'date' => 'Mon, 18 Apr 2016 14:27:37 +0000',

  ),
   'crypt' =>
  array (
    'key' => '51b8c74ff74f2b568c1025da3b4be0f4',
  ),
  'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),
  'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'fashmart247',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
  ),
  'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
  ),
);
```

Comment: What do i have to edit? apologies for my question, i have just been reading too many articles but i just need clarity.

Comment: The file you need to edit is **app/etc/env.php**. Please consider to mark an answer as solution if you think it solved your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Magento 2, the equivalent to **app/etc/local.xml** is **app/etc/env.php**.

You need to edit that file and everything should be fine.

#### In case you need an example...

```
  'db' =>
  array (
    'connection' =>
    array (
      'indexer' =>
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => '<your_database_name>',
        'username' => '<your_database_username>',
        'password' => '<your_database_password>',
        'active' => '1',
        'persistent' => NULL,
      ),
      'default' =>
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => '<your_database_name>',
        'username' => '<your_database_username>',
        'password' => '<your_database_password>',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
```

#### In case you are a lazy coder just like me...

Create a custom command in Magento 2

**app/code/Octopius/Commands/Console/Command/SwitchToLive.php**

```
<?php

namespace Octopius\Commands\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * An Abstract class for support tool related commands.
 */
class SwitchToLiveCommand extends Command
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_fileManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $fileManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->_fileManager = $fileManager;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Define the shell command
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configure()
    {

        $this->setName('switch:env:live')
            ->setDescription('Switch environment file...');
        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * Execute function
     * @param InputInterface  $input  Input
     * @param OutputInterface $output Output
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @return null|int null or 0 if everything went fine, or an error code
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Switching to live environment...');
        $liveEnv = BP . '/' . 'app/etc/env.php.live';
        $env = BP . '/' . 'app/etc/env.php';

        if ($this->_fileManager->fileExists($liveEnv)) {
            $this->_fileManager->mv($liveEnv, $env);
        }

        $output->writeln('Environment switched successfully.');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Octopius/Commands/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="octopiusSwitchToLiveCommand" xsi:type="object">Octopius\Commands\Console\Command\SwitchToLiveCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Octopius/Commands/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Octopius_Commands" setup_version="0.1.0"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Octopius/Commands/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Octopius_Commands',
    __DIR__
);
```

Obviously, make sure you have **app/etc/env.php.live** before start using `bin/magento switch:env:live`

Comment: OK so you saying the same information edited in local.xml, is what i have to edit in env.php

Comment: @Josephine: Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Tony: Great i guess i can move forward from here. Just one question, do i edit before on localhost or when i have moved the to live server

Comment: @Tony great you have just helped me get things sorted. thumps up.

Answer (score 2):

In magento1 Local.xml has credentials for connection to DB. In magento2 credentials are stored in file env.php. Just edit in this file credentials for DB.