# Am trying to import mysqldump but getting error "#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, database

How can i fix in order to have a smooth import to phpmyadmin on cpanel... I am getting error `#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Magento.

Comment: this is a magento table question..

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism.. Am moving magento from xampp localhost to live server and i have a problem moving phpmyadmin. how is it not a megento question please?

Comment: maybe you should check that out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are talking about Magento2, right?
If so, check for Mysql Version, because Magento2 needs at least a Mysql with version 5.6 or higher.

This is a 'default' error, if you try to import a Magento2 Mysql Dump into a Mysql Server with Version 5.5 or lower

Comment: yes you are right. ok will check the versions. Thanks

Comment: I see that i was right regarding your question yesterday: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111491/i-want-to-move-magento2-to-live-server-but-no-app-etc-local-xml-in-my-magento-2
For sure your lamp stack is more up2date then your cpanel server.
If this is the error, it would be nice, if you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to first create backup of your `app/etc/env.php` file. Then upload a fresh `env.php` file to the `pp/etc` folder then run your store then the `setup wizard` will come and after that with that wizard you can check that your server can `fulfilled` all requirements for magento2 or not.